# Having problems using $.each and wrapInner() in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to iterate through a list of elements and wrap them in a link tag. However, my list displays differently than I want to.

Here is what it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/eMexU/

HTML

```
<div id="list" data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Item 4</a></li>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like when I use $.each and wrapInner(): http://jsfiddle.net/zpFDa/1/

HTML

```
<div id="list" data-role="listview">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#list li").each(function () {
    $(this).wrapInner('<a href="http://google.com/"></a>')
});
```

Comment: You cant do this without replacing `li` in order to get listview styled. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KtBcU/

Comment: Something in the `listview` widget is keeping this from working. I think you should report it.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this, is replacing existing `li` with new ones and then call `.listview('refresh')` to apply styles / enhance markup.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KtBcU/)**

```
$("#list li").each(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).replaceWith('<li><a href="http://google.com/">' + text + '</a></li>')
});

$('#list').listview('refresh');
```